# Matching string characters in regex

Tags: ruby, regex

How do we represent a string in ruby like for integer we do \d, is it \s in ruby?

I tried \s and \c*, but nothing worked for me. I have a constraint in my file as per below:

```
constraints: {:name => /\s+/}
```

but its not accepting \s for some reason. For integer I use `constraints: {:id => /\d+/}` and it works.

Comment: Arbitrary string? Or are there any constraints on the string at all, like must be alphanumeric?

Answer (score 1):

For word characters you would use:

```
constraints: {:name => /\w+/}
```

`\s` is whitespace, so it wouldn't mark words.

you could also use:

```
constraints: {:name => /\S+/}
```

This will check for any NON-whitespace chars.

It depends on what exactly you're wanting to match.

http://rubular.com/ (contains a list with its practice box)

Comment: You might want to see what `'é' =~ /\w+/` is.

Comment: Thanks for your replay and sharing the link. I am using a string which will contain words but can also contain white spaces in between words. Will try the link you gave to see if it can handle both words and space, else might will have to think of handling spaces separately.

Comment: For example :name in my case could be "This is a name"

Comment: @tech_learning It seems like you want to match everything… What *don’t* you want to match?